# Effectively getting the root domain from url without the tld without using a predefined tld list

Tags: javascript, regex

My question is simple. How does one go about remove the tld from a domain using regex for example, without a predefined list of every possible tld known to existence. It seems simple enough, but yet I've not found a single one on stackoverflow nor on google without the use of a list or it not working with diverse tlds such as .co.uk or com.au with using the pop method simply rendering it useless. For this, the `http://www. or http://` is already removed for this scenario.

```
google.com --> google 
google.co.uk --> google

stackoverflow.com --> stackoverflow
```

Thank you

Comment: its impossible.... you need a tld list...

Comment: Isn't it possible to remove all past the first dot of a domain? google"."co.uk

Comment: maps.google.com ?? The site isnt maps...

Comment: You could get 80% correct trough removing all 3 or shorter, then take the last. This will mostly work (except db.de or page.hamburg or air.aero etc)

Comment: I am looking to use this with links that have had all sub-domains and prior characters removed. The current pop examples on here leave sites like google.co.uk looking like co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its impossible (if you care about subdomains)

If you dont care about subdomains:

```
domain=url.split(".").shift();
```

If you care about subdomains,
The most correct way, (sth about 80% correct) would be removing everything short from.the url, then take the last:

```
domain=url.split(".").filter(e=>e.length>3).pop();
if(domain==undefined){
  domain=url.split(".").pop();
 }
```

That would fail with account.db.de stadt.hamburg etc, but without a tld list, this isnt possible.

Comment: This works for both .co.uk and .com to leave "google" for example?

Comment: Test it. It should do that

Comment: trying domain=url.split(".").unshift(); on google through console leaves simply "4"

Comment: Sorry should be shift

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do it perfectly.

Comment: While asking, I doubt there is a method to remove the tld with a sub domain is in the domain? Just wondering.